# Kinetic energy of an object at rest

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames

Why don't we consider that an object on Earth has kinetic energy as it is also moving at the rotating speed of Earth?

Comment: It's also in orbit about the Sun. It's orbiting the centre of the Milky Way. It's on a collision course with the Andromeda galaxy. It's moving relative to the barycentre of our super-cluster. Why not include all of those as motions for its kinetic energy?

Comment: The kinetic energy depends on the frame of reference. If you start wondering how to define an invariant definition and a transformation between frames, you will probably reinvent special relativity.

Answer (score 19):

Because in the frame of reference that is co-rotating, the object doesn't move, and therefore it has no kinetic energy in that frame, which is the frame in which most problems involving objects on earth are looked at. Note that kinetic energy is evidently *not* a frame-invariant quantity, but it is not required to be.

Answer (score 4):

The exact quantities of kinetic energy (like momentum) depend on your choice of a reference frame.  Don't get too worried though; regardless of your choice of a reference frame, you will find that energy (and likewise momentum) is conserved within the reference frame.  Therefore, two observers may not agree on the kinetic energy or momentum of an object, but they will both be able to verify conservation of energy or momentum within a system.