# Can we measure kenetic energy on an absolute scale, or does it have to be measured with reference to something else?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames

I recently read the question [Kinetic energy of an object at rest](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147608/) where it was suggested that the kinetic energy of an object on Earth is measured in the reference frame of Earth.

Can we measure kinetic energy free of a frame of reference? Does the concept even makes sense? And if kinetic energy needs to be measured in a frame of reference, then does potential energy need to as well?

Comment: What does that say about conservation of energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinetic energy is the energy associated with motion. Therefore, we can no more measure kinetic energy free of a reference frame than we can say something is moving free of a reference frame. It must always be moving with respect to something.

Energy is conserved because the total energy of a system is the same before and after a process in the same frame of reference. If you change the reference frame, it has no meaning to compare it to another frame in terms of whether energy is conserved or not

Comment: I see. Okay, another question. Take some system in some frame of reference and an observer there will say that energy is conserved. If an observer in another frame of reference sees the same process they should also conclude that energy is conserved (they are taking measurements w.r.t. their frame of reference so they can make a valid comparison). Are you saying that both observers agree that energy is conserved, but that they might disagree as to the measurements?

Comment: I'd really love to ask about relativistic effects of reference frames moving fast w.r.t. each other at this point, but I think that might push this out of bounds.

Comment: @kleineg yes, they would agree that energy is conserved and they might disagree on the value of total energy. If you want to ask about the relativistic effects, you should take a look at some of the related questions on this site. If you still think your questions are unanswered, you can always ask another question

Comment: No, that answers the question I had, and went down the rabbit hole a little. I accept answers after a day in most cases.